# Many Foreign Key Restraints Depending on Many Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, innodb

Note: This question may possibly be poorly asked as my knowledge of SQL is quite limited.

We have 3 tables, **BUILDINGS**, **FLOORS**, **ROOMS**.

**BUILDINGS** contains the columns: Building_ID(its primary key), and Name(its name)

**FLOORS** contains the columns: Floor_ID(its primary key), Name(its name), and Building_ID(foreign key to **BUILDINGS**' primary key)

**ROOMS** contains the columns: Room_ID(its primary key), Name(its name), Building_ID(foreign key to **BUILDINGS**' primary key), and Floor_ID(foreign key to **FLOORS**' primary key)

My problem is, if I have two buildings, 1 and 2, and two floors, 1 and 2, if floor 1 belongs to building 1, and floor 2 belongs to building 2 (that is building 2 has no floor 1, and building 1 has no floor 2) it is possible to add a room which is in building 1, floor 2, even though this should not exist.

How can I correct my structure to ensure only valid rooms may be added? And if I were to scale out again, another table **DESKS** which would have an associated **BUILDING**, **FLOOR**, and **ROOM** would this solution still work?

Comment: 1. Normalization:  the ROOMS table does not need the "Building_id" because the FLOORS table already has this relationship.  2. A floor can only belong to a building: you need to define a composite unique index (Floor_id, Building_id) in the FLOORS table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create 3 tables. Room only need to reference floor. And browsing floors you will know buildings

```
CREATE TABLE Building
    (`building_id` int, `name` varchar(6))
;

CREATE TABLE floor
    (`floor_id` int, `building_id` int, `name` varchar(7))
;

CREATE TABLE room
    (`room_id` int, `floor_id` int, `name` varchar(9))
;
```

Querys

```
SELECT *
FROM Building;

SELECT *
FROM Building B;
INNER JOIN floor F 
    ON B.building_id = F.building_id
;

SELECT *
FROM Building B;
INNER JOIN floor F     
    ON B.building_id = F.building_id
INNER JOIN Room R
    ON F.room_id = R.room_id
;
```

And for `DESKS`

```
CREATE TABLE desks
    (`desk_id` int, `room_id` int, `name` varchar(9))
;

SELECT *
FROM Building B;
INNER JOIN floor F     
    ON B.building_id = F.building_id
INNER JOIN Room R
    ON F.floor_id = R.floor_id
INNER JOIN Desk D
    ON R.room_id = D.room_id
;
```

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. Thanks, this was daunting and confusing me to no end. The solution was very practical in the end!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is one of normalization. In your ROOMS table, do not include the foreign key Building_ID. The connection between ROOM and BUILDINGS is via the FLOORS table. A second connection is unnecessary, since any queries you run can join through those tables to get the building name.